# TypeError 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de tomar los numeros de una lista y convertirlos tambien en listas. El ejercicio tiene como entrada una cantidad de numeros calquiera, y el ultimo numero ingresado debe ser -1. La salida consiste en tomar cada uno de los digitos de esos numeros excepto el -1, y si todos los digitos que componen el numero son pares, el numero es hyperpar, de lo contrario no. La verdad no se me ocurre como hacer para que en esa lista inicial, (que contiene los numeros ingresados ​​excepto el -1), sus elementos queden como sublistas dentro de ella. La idea que tengo es mediante un ciclo recorrer cada digito de la sublista para resolver el problema, pero no se como.

Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora.

```
def esPar(N):
  if N%2 ==0:
    return True
  return False  

lista_de_numeros=[]
while True:   
 numero= int(input())
 lista_de_numeros.append(numero)
 if numero == -1:
   break
print(lista_de_numeros)

for i in range(len(lista_de_numeros)-1):
  lista_de_numeros(str[i])
print(lista_de_numeros)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo puedes hacer con una comprensión de listas para que cada dígito de un número se convierta en un elemento de una sub lista

```
lista_de_numeros.append([int(a) for a in str(numero)])
```

Por cierto, para que el -1 no aparezca en tu lista podrías cambiar la posición del `append()` después del `if` en ese caso si el número ingresado es "-1" entonces el `while` se interrumpe y el "-1" no se guarda en tu lista.

Ahora, el error `TypeError` te aparece porque tu variable `lista_de_numeros` es una lista, para acceder a los índices necesitas corchetes `[]` pero tu estas utilizando paréntesis `()` (**NOTA: Ver aclaración al final**)

No se bién lo que intentas hacer en esa línea pero si cambias tus paréntesis por corchetes entonces no vas a tener ese error

```
lista_de_numeros[i]
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
def esPar(N):
    if N%2 ==0:
        return True
    return False  

lista_de_numeros=[]
while True:   
    numero= int(input())
    if numero == -1:
        break
    lista_de_numeros.append([int(a) for a in str(numero)])
print(lista_de_numeros)

for i in range(len(lista_de_numeros)-1):
    lista_de_numeros[i]
print(lista_de_numeros)
```

Si ingresamos:

```
 5
 26
 32
 -1
```

Obtenemos:

```
[[5], [2, 6], [3, 2]]
```

**Edición:** Gracias Christian por el comentario aclarando que el error no es provocado por el uso de paréntesis en la variable `lista_de_numeros`. El error proviene de los "argumentos" que se le estaría pasando donde se hace `str[i]`. Pues el error dice que un objeto no es "subscriptable" por ello el error original o el que muestra python proviene de ahí `str[i]` ya que si fuese por los paréntesis el error sería `object is not callable`.

Comment: Lo curioso es que el error no es provocado por el uso de paréntesis en la variable `lista_de_numeros`. El error proviene de los "argumentos" que se le estaría pasando donde se hace `str[i]`. Pues el error dice que un objeto no es "subscriptable" por ello el error original o el que muestra python proviene de ahí `str[i]` ya que si fuese por los paréntesis el error sería `object is not callable`

Comment: @Christian, Gracias por la aclaración, ahora edito la respuesta para evitar desinformación

Comment: @Christian, ahora veo todo un poco mas claro, sin embargo trate de usar un for anidado para evaluar cada digito de los numeros, me aparece el error  object of type 'int' has no len(), pero no entiendo poe que si el indice i que estoy recorriendo ya es una lista.

Comment: @Christian, lo otro es que como debo hacer para que cuando evalue los digitos, no me imprima por ejemplo la salida: 42842 es hyperpar en el ciclo.

Comment: @victorManuelparraparra, es importante mantener una sola pregunta en cada publicación, de esa forma otros usuarios pueden encontrar la respuesta a preguntas similares. Por favor crea una nueva pregunta y agrega el código que usas actualmente (Probablemente cambió después de esta respuesta) y describe el problema que tienes y lo que esperarías obtener en la salida

Comment: @victorManuelparraparra, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas